# Bootstrap Modal on header link not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Thank you so much for going to this post. i greatly appreciate it :) by the way the modal is working but when i add it on my menu its not firing up or showing up when click but on other button it works.

the link is on my header.php it has this code **"href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal""** but on my footer link it work but when i add it on my header its not working.

```
          <div id="header" class="alt">
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="special">


                                <a href="#menu"  class="menuToggle" id="welcomeDivs"><span> menu</span></a>

                                <div id="menu">
                                  <div class="logo_menu">
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png">
                                 </div> 
                                        <ul>
                                        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/company-values">Company Values</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/our-services">Our services</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="mbtn" href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" >Need Home health care now?</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/meet-the-team">Meet the Team</a></li>
                                    </ul>





                                </div>


                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>
```

Modal Code is on my footer.php

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                   <p class="cl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> ClOSE</p>

                </div>
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">


            <!-- First Div -->
 <div class="col-md-6 conone condits">
    <h4>Contact us</h4>

</div>

            <!-- END First Div -->


            <!-- Second Div -->

 <div class="col-md-6 conone">
                                <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
       <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="52" title="send"]' ); ?>
</div>
            <!-- END Second Div -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you make sure jQuery is called `before` bootstrap is, in the head ? I already saw (failing) attempts to link all stuff before footer

Comment: @techno check the console for any errors.

Comment: @OldPadawan Awesome! Thank didnt try that because when i add it on my logo link it work but right now its already working thank you

Comment: glad it helped...